# Multiple passport-jwt strategy in the same app

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I created two different passport-jwt using different passwords and use it to authenticate two different roles?

Example:

```
var passport_admin = require('../../node_modules/passport'); 
var passport_user = require('../../node_modules/passport'); 

require('../auth_layer/admin_jwt_auth')(passport_admin); 
require('../auth_layer/user_jwt_auth')(passport_user); 

app.post('/admin/profile',passport_admin.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}), business_admin.post_profile);

app.post('/user/profile',passport_user.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}), business_admin.post_profile);
```

When I do the above it does not work(401 when verifying token) because I require two different authentication midleware in my route.

How can I achieve that? or Does it make sense to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the same passport strategy for different routes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846711/how-to-use-the-same-passport-strategy-for-different-routes)

Answer (score 24):

I had exactly the same issue with you but after a number of research, trials and errors, I found my own method in solving this problem and wanted to share it with you.
First on your syntax below, **only one rule will be implemented**:

```
    var passport_admin = require('../../node_modules/passport'); 
    var passport_user = require('../../node_modules/passport');
```

The rule which will be used is only the **latest** which is **passport_user**.
To tackle this, you need to go to your passport.js api and create two passport rules with different names (in the same js file) like below

```
    passport.use('admin-rule',
    new JwtStrategy(opts, (...........) => {.........
    }));

    passport.use('user-rule',
    new JwtStrategy(opts, (...........) => {.........
    }));
```

Then you want to use the 'admin-rule' on your admin syntax, same idea with user syntax (use 'user-rule').

```
    app.post('/admin/profile',passport_admin.authenticate('admin-rule'
    {session:false}), business_admin.post_profile);
```

That way your admin & user will use the specified passport rule on it's router.

Answer (score 0):

This solution allows you to use the same url for both strategies, just name them.

https://github.com/mikenicholson/passport-jwt/issues/182